# Cross Browser Debugging between Firefox and Safari (or Chrome)

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

I've noticed that Safari and Chrome behave the same when it comes to HTML and CSS.   However, there are differences between Firefox and Safari (and hence, Chrome as well).

Sometimes things can look great in Firefox, but the CSS misbehaves in Safari and Chrome.  The cause of the mis-behaviour can be attributed to "anything" (as opposed to in IE 6 and 7, mis-behaviours are usually caused by excessive paddings/margins that cause elements to float out of position).  For example, while debugging CSS of a website for Safari the following attributes have caused cross-browser misbehaviours:

- position
- height
- width
- padding
- margin

Is there a common pattern to Chrome and Safari CSS debugging?

Can you guys offer insight into the differences between Safari and Firefox that may help me with my cross browser debugging?
Thanks

Comment: You realise that Safari and Chrome both use the same rendering engine (Webkit)? The differences between Firefox and Chrome/Safari are due to the different rendering engine (Gecko, for Firefox).

Comment: @David - that means nothing. Google's is very customized.

Comment: @orokusaki, while I'm aware that Google have customised their implementation, I've yet to come across a situation where Chrome renders a valid (x)html page with any major differences to Safari.

Comment: @orokusaki, I suppose I should qualify my previous assertion, I'm a Linux boy, mostly, using Windows only when I'm not at my own machine. Which is thankfully rare, these days. Do you recall which site, by any chance? I'm curious to see the difference.

Comment: @David - It was one I was developing. There are a number of minor differences that you won't notice until you do some serious CSS with all sorts of features. One right off the bat that's easy: `border-radius: 3px;` works in Chrome, but not in Safari.

Comment: @orokusaki, ah, I had wondered about the `border-radius` one, ever since I discovered (by accident) that it worked natively in Chrome and, so far as I could remember at the time, only with the `-vendor-` prefix in Safari. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, and anecdotally, the majority of large differences between cross-browser rendering of the same page are due to:

- invalid (x)html, use the on-line html validator from the [W3](http://validator.w3.org) to ensure the validity of the mark-up.
- lack of establishing a base-line for CSS (as [@Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755215/cross-browser-debugging-between-firefox-and-safari-or-chrome/3756625#3756625) suggests: use a css reset).
- use of CSS which varies in support from browser-to-browser, particularly the newer CSS 3 ([`transitions`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/), [`column-count`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) and [`box-reflect`](http://webkit.org/blog/182/css-reflections/)<sup>1</sup> particularly, though there are many, many others).

---

1. This may, or may not be, a proposal for inclusion in CSS3 by the World Wide Web Consortium, the only references I've found for it are exclusively with the `-webkit` vendor prefix, which suggests that it's *probably* a proprietary extension. I can, however, hope that others will follow suit. It's so much easier to apply reflections with css than with js/php...

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed differences, but not that dramatic. As usual, most differences can easily be overcome / avoided by using a css-reset. Do you use one on the pages you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

This css difference is because, there is a default styles difference for firefox and chrome browsers. click this links for default css sheets

http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/layout/style/html.css
http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css

While developing the webpage itself we have to make sure of overriding this default styling commonly for both browsers. using the browser extensions like -webkit and -moz etc..

After development and in debugging state, we need to override this default styles. I don't think we have any common debugging for this. correct me if i am wrong.